# Visually Editting AXML file in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, xamarin

My VS2010 won't allow me to visually edit AXML files.  I want to configure the "Open With..." feature in VS to run the visual editor.

The "Open With" feature is available by right-clicking a file in the solution.

Another one of my VS installations has this feature so I know it's possible.  There must be something in the Xamarin install that this feature doesn't get setup some times.

Does anyone know how to set this up manually via the "Open With..." selection dialog?

Right now, I switch back and forth between Mono Develop and VS...what a pain...

Comment: I have the option to set the _Android Designer_ as the default in VS 2010. Maybe re-install MonoDroid?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be the case you should just be able to select the file from the Resources/Layout folder and have the option of either the Source/Design view. If you are unable to do this just use the Xamarin Studio as you have been doing but it might also be a idea to use the DroidDraw website www.droiddraw.org/ in order to have a GUI to design your interfaces.

Hope this helps,
James